# Making a shadow copy of files that are being copied to USB flash drive (C++)

Tags: c++

I have the task described in the title. Googling gave me a ton of compiled .exe programs that make a FULL shadow copy of the USB flash drive when it connects to PC. But I don't need the full copy of the flash drive, I just need to shadowly get the copy of file when it is being copied to the flash drive. How can I do it? Write a .bat file? Make a Visual C++ project? Please help. Thanks. Sorry for my English, it's not my native.

Comment: As currently written, your question is too broad. You are looking for [ReadDirectoryChanges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx), or [wrapper for your language](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].